# Default GNU Linker Script name so VIM does Syntax Highlighting

Tags: vim, linker-scripts

What is the usual suffix for a linker script so that VIM will use syntax-highlighting on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be *.ld*, only from what I see Vim doesn't come (at least mine doesn't, 7.3.) with the syntax files for it. Try the ones offered for download [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20170806213950/http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Syntax-indent-files-for-GNU-ld-scripts-td1140159.html).

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Apr 16 2010 13:34:36) does support it on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Comment: It doesn't seem to very good syntax highlighting. ABSOLUTE(.); colours the opening and closing parentheses differently!